# picture in header hide first picture in docx with python-docx

Tags: python, image, python-docx

In a Document of docx in python,
when an image is added to the header, the first next picture does not appear.
The image is visible with LibreOffice (7.0) but not with MS Office(365). And MS Office asks to repair the file after a modification in the file.

```
from docx import Document as DocumentDocx  # for creating docx files
from docx.shared import Cm  # section parameters
file_list = ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4']


document = DocumentDocx()

section = document.sections[0]

header = section.header
p = header.add_paragraph('')
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture('logo.png', height=Cm(1))


p = document.add_paragraph()
p.alignment = 1
run = p.add_run()
run.add_text('1')
for ii, name_file in enumerate(file_list):
    run.add_text(str(ii))
    run.add_picture(name_file + '.png', width=Cm(12))

document.save('file' + '.docx')
```

How to correctly add a picture in header and show all pictures ?

Answer (score 0):

The missing image is due to Word (version greater than 2105), and only if there is image in header section of the existing word document
as [eamars say it](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/981#issuecomment-891395503).